# FragmentWindow, fragment inside a window

Tags: android, fragment

How do I display a fragment inside of a window. FragmentDialog does what I want, but I want
the possibility to hide/show the window, without destroying the instance.

I thought I could do something like this, but I didn't work as intended
with fragmentdialog, since I need to use fragment.show(fragmentManager, "tag")

```
if (fragment.isHidden()) {
  fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
} else {
  fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment);
}
ft.commit();
```